# Skip particular Javascript execution in HTML unit

Tags: htmlunit

I have a URL. I want to fetch Page-Source of the URL after executing Java Scripts.

[Fetch Page source using HtmlUnit : URL got stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396052/fetch-page-source-using-htmlunit-url-got-stuck)

Initially I suspected that it is due to system resource and High CPU usage, that the URL is getting stuck.

Then I tried to run it on HTML UNIT 2.9 and 2.11. It got stuck on both while parsing. Refer  [the above question for HTML UNIT code scrape that is getting stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396052/fetch-page-source-using-htmlunit-url-got-stuck).

Now I am suspecting that this might be due to JS Execution going into infinite loop.

I want to check what JS files are causing problem and remove them from execution.

If they are JS for sites like google analytics, twitter etc, I may not need them at all.

So I want to find a way to tell HTML Unit to ignore certain JS file and execute the rest.

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this. It worked for me:

```java
class InterceptWebConnection extends FalsifyingWebConnection{
    public InterceptWebConnection(WebClient webClient) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        super(webClient);
    }
    @Override
    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
        WebResponse response=super.getResponse(request);
        if(response.getWebRequest().getUrl().toString().endsWith("dom-drag.js")){
            return createWebResponse(response.getWebRequest(), "", "application/javascript", 200, "Ok");
        }
        return super.getResponse(request);
    }
}
```

then write following while setting up your `webClient`

```java
new InterceptWebConnection(webClient);
```

Comment: I also faced the same issue.

Comment: Hi, my web client is created list this WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); Where should I add this interception?