# Selenium Web Driver click action

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I have a code in selenium which dynamically clicks on the tabs in menu page. And sometimes happens that tab is not clickable(it is just a plain `td` with `span` inside) and when `Web Driver` tries to click on this tab, my program gets frozen (no exception thrown or anything).

I can't avoid clicking on tabs like that but I would like to somehow prevent that freeze after click. So can I set some timeout or tell to selenium what to do if element is not clickable?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    format("//span[@class='rf-tab-lbl'][text()='{0}']",
        navigation.getGroup()))).click();
//if the tab is currently selected (hence is not clickable) selenium won't click 
// on it and program freezes
```

Comment: What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: The thing is that it shouldn't freeze. When you click it manually on the page, does it freeze, too? Try to click it with Firebug to see whether it's firing some kind of response that could trick WebDriver. If it's waiting for some script, you might try setting a [script timeout](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#setScriptTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). `driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(...)`, although I don't think it will help.

Comment: Also, what is the difference in the clickable and unclickable tab? Couldn't you just check whether the element is contained in a `<td>` instead of an `<a>` element, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try another page from a different website. It might be a JS looping issue. 
I encountered such an issue in HtmlUnit for some URLs. 
I raised issue in HtmlUnit user group. 
They told me that JS infinite loop was causing freez. 
Time out did not work for me as well.

I tried to apply my own time out. That did not work too.

Refer following question for applying own timeout

[HtmlUnit WebClient Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559746/htmlunit-webclient-timeout)

If it works for another website, problem might be site specific. 
You can attach source of Selenium in eclipse and check / debug where it is getting stuck. 
I did same for HtmlUnit. I reached to parse method, which did not come out.

If still does not work, contact Selenium support.